# Trying to change uid to user, but says it already exists

Tags: linux, uid

I'm trying to change the UID of user `ec2-user` to 500, when I try the following command getting the error UID already exists.

```
sudo usermod -u 500 ec2-user
usermod: UID '500' already exists
```

I'm doing a grep of `/etc/passwd` and can't find UID 500, so not sure how I can accomplish this.

Comment: Have you checked /etc/group and /etc/shadow?

Comment: Yes, there's no referene of UID 500

Answer (score 3):

[According to the source code](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/ae169c40468bc9d016016880613c01aca6050b60/libmisc/prefix_flag.c#L223), `usermod` uses `getpwuid` for [checking whether an uid already exists](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/ae169c40468bc9d016016880613c01aca6050b60/src/usermod.c#L1446) if the `prefix` flag is not used.

As stated in the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid) of `getpwuid`, it can also lookup the users from LDPA etc.:

> The getpwnam() function returns a pointer to a structure containing the broken-
> out fields of the record in the password database (e.g., the local password file
> /etc/passwd, NIS, and LDAP) that matches the username name.
>
> The getpwuid() function returns a pointer to a structure containing the broken-
> out fields of the record in the password database that matches the user ID uid.

You can run `getent passwd 500` for checking whether the uid already exists.
According to the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html) `getent passwd` passes each numeric key to `getpwuid` and displays the result.
You can also see `/etc/nsswitch.conf` for checking your current configuration.